# EF query value to ViewModel

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel

I have a EF query in which 3 columns will be fetched based on some condition on other tables also. The output columns are ID, Month and revenue. I want to show this information on View but how?

I have no knowledge to use ViewModel here.
The query is:

```
var serviceList1 = (from p in dbObj.ServiceWiseRevenues
                               group p by new { p.service_id, p.pdate.Month } into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   ID = g.Key.service_id,
                                   Month = g.Key.Month,
                                   Revenue = g.Sum(c => c.total_revenue / c.tbService.tbCountry.CountryCurrencyConversionRate)
                               }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Month).ToList();      
            return View(serviceList1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `serviceList1` is a list of anonymous objects. It would be non-trivial to use those in a View, because their type is generated by the .NET Runtime.

Better is to define a ViewModel class like this (probably in folder `/Models`):

```
public class RevByMonth
{
    int ID { get; set; },
    int Month { get; set; },
    double Revenue { get; set; },
}
```

And then replace the `select new { ... }` part with this:

```
select new RevByMonth
{
    ID = g.Key.service_id,
    Month = g.Key.Month,
    Revenue = g.Sum(...)
}
```

Finally specify the type `RevByMonth` in the model of the View:

```
@model List<RevByMonth>
// rest of View code, e.g. foreach (var revenue in Model) ...
```

Comment: Hi Peter thanks alot for the prompt reply. I have changed my code as you mentioned but there is a datatype conversion error on ID and Revenue.

Comment: For ID it is cannot implicitly convert type int? to int and for Revenue its double? to double.

Comment: This is the most basic of things. Note that my class is just an example and in most cases you'd need to use the types that you get from the database. Although for an ID it is questionable that it could be a nullable int (or `int?`), so then you should try to stick with `int` in the class, and using `ID = g.Key.service_id.Value` for the assignment. This should work if all items have an ID, which they should have in almost any normal scenario.

Comment: Thanks alot peter, you make my day. Now i want to add some more complexity. I want to convert month no. to month name like Dec'16, so i have to use AsEnumerable for this. So now how can i use my ViewModel in this particular case. Thanks

Comment: No problem, but don't ask follow-up questions as comments, if you really need then create a new question.

Comment: unable to create a new questions, but I have to sort it out. 
 
I want to group data on Month + Year like Jan'16, Feb'16 in the same query already posted. Pls help.